# Turning stretched raster image to RGB 3 bands

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, landsat, rgb

I'm using a 2012 landsat image for a time series image analysis. The original image had 3 bands colors composite, after  image processing, because the original image had scanline errors, the result was a streched raster . Now, I need the 3 bands RGB to fulfill the image classification.

How can I turn a stretched raster image to RGB 3 bands?

[image]

Comment: You've probably only processed the first band. ArcGIS only uses the first band in a multi band image for some processing. You can add each band seprately and process that, then stack into a 3 band composite.